# NextJS - error when SSR is used in Cloud Run

Tags: next.js, google-cloud-run

I'm using NextJs in Google Cloud Run and I can't figure out what may cause this error. It happens on all pages that use SSR, others are fine.

```
Error: Invariant: render should have used routeModule at NextNodeServer.renderHTMLImpl
```

and

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dev') at renderToHTMLImpl
```

both pointing to nextjs code.

My config:

```
const prod = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
const runtimeCaching = require('next-pwa/cache');

const withPWA = require('next-pwa')({
  dest: 'public',
  mode: 'production',
  disable: prod ? false : true,
  runtimeCaching,
});

module.exports = withPWA({
  images: {
    domains: [
      'some_domains_here',
    ],
  },
  output: 'standalone',
  staticPageGenerationTimeout: 10000,
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL,
  },
});
```

I'm stuck, what should I look for?